# self-hypnotization-autosuggestion - chanting

Tags: chanting, autosuggestion

I am looking for a solution for my complete lack of control  - tried many things (doing lot of meditation doing 1 minute meditation - no formal meditation - but i never manage to keep it more than a few days usually 1-2 days even with only 1 minute meditation a day)

what im trying to do now is to avoid doing bad stuff in hopes to do good stuff  but i have no self control and always fail in it

thought about a way to change that using some self-hypnosis  - auto suggestion something i asked about here :

[Should I use autosuggestion to make myself meditate](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/14330/should-i-use-autosuggestion-to-make-myself-meditate)

now im thinking of doing chanting of sabba papassa akranam  (As to the focus of avoiding doing bad i will do good)   maybe during the day maybe just repeat it 108 times one time a day ?

Do you think this will have a benefit ? can this "work" and cause a big change ?   any tips advice on how to this ?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, best maybe just ten times, when possible situations appear which could be approached by bad thoughts, words or deeds before not doing such. That's the most effective time with most benefical fruits, and if doing seriously and heedfull, watching over it's requirement, Breath will see it's great effects very soon.

Best make a strong resolve and promise to do. Maybe by chanting 108 times, having bowed before the Three Juwels, taken refuge in a small personal sermon. Before going to bed every day, in the case if chanting in such situations was forgotten, chant it 108 times and renew the promis like at the beginning. If having chanted if in situations and did not do the deeds then, best rejoice on it and try to just dwell silently in this joy. If feeling inspired, maybe good to devote gratitude to the Gems at the end.

*[Note: This is a gift of Dhamma and not meant for commercial purpose or other low wordily gains by means of trade and exchange. It's given as guest and not as subscriber, as possibility given by the owner of this page here.]*

Answer (score 1):

In my experience autosuggestion can help.

Things to try telling yourself:

- "I am seeing the wonderful, always usefulness of meditation"
- "I love to sit and be aware"
- "I am enjoying being free of crazy activity"
- "I am feeling good sitting here to work on my spiritual cultivation rather than scurrying about in materialistic existence"
- "I am stable and normal becoming free of external influences"
- "I am growing in my basic living skill of being aware and calm"
- "I am not attached to any phenomena even this affirmation itself"
- "I am not attached to not being attached"

Basically, the affirmations are not going to lead you to concentration or enlightenment directly but they will help you reign in your crazy worldly mind so that you can keep practicing!

However, use the affirmation itself as an object of awareness. See it working its way into you.
Smile. Breathe.
Do not attach to the process of affirmation and try to focus your mind 99% on the Buddhadharma itself.

You are only using affirmation as a tool to get yourself out of your neurotic, scattered habits.

After you are calm, steady and concentrated, you will be cultivating closer to jhana and it will be important to learn to concentrate even when you don't feel like--observing the "not wanting to sit" as another phenomena.
You cannot just affirmation away those kind of things. You will need to cultivate actual meditation.

Anyway, those are some early stage and mid-stage tips for you. Hope that helped.

Comment: what about  "not doing bad stuff"    chanting specifically ?  not to remind myself but to make myself control myself for example not to watch youtube videos for fun

Comment: Yes, chanting can really direct the mind but I wouldn't include "I am" because it reinforces the worry that it is increasing my attachment to ego. I would replace "I am" with "Imagine" or "Imagine when there was ". So, I would say, "Imagine when there was love to sit and be aware" or "Imagine feeling good sitting here to work on  spiritual cultivation" or "Imagine being full of energy".

Comment: @breath try to visualize the satisfied feeling of doing something else. Or death visualization is the proper buddhist technique.